# How to show subitems below an item in a listview in C#?

Tags: c#, listview

Is there a way to show the subitems of an item in a listview below it? I don't want to separate the item in first column and subsequent subitems in subsequent columns, I want it all in a single column and if there were to be more items I want every item separated by a line. Something like this but in C#.

[image]

Maybe if it is not possible could it be to make every item like an expandable list?

My code for now is:

```
lstEvents.View = View.Details;
lstEvents.ForeColor = Color.Black;
lstEvents.Columns.Add("Events");
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("Event name");
item.SubItems.Add("23/04/2012");
item.SubItems.Add("$20000");
item.SubItems.Add("this would be the event description");
```

im using windows forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Tile view, each "column" appears as a "row" under the primary column. This will give you what you asked for, but probably not what you want.

You can owner draw the Tile view to produce something like this

[image: Owner drawn Tile view]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/_images/tileview-ownerdrawn2.png))</sub>

You can do this all yourself using just a plain ListView, but the [ObjectListView project](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/) makes this *much* easier.

Comment: hey thanks that's exactly what i wanted, i used the tile view, read it's documentation and it gave me the result i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass the listview and do it yourself.

Or, you can tag certain rows as subrows of the one above it using `.Tag = IndexOfPreviousRow` and track the relationships in a model. It's kinda hacky, though.

As far as doing it natively with the .NET listview, I don't believe you can.